# BOF - EOF error

Tags: sql, asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I'm getting this error with my asp page when i try to run a SQL query:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bcd'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

The code is:

```
' -- connect to Database1.accdb database --

set conn1 = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
conn1.open "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source =  C:\Users\nam2611\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\Database3.accdb"

' -- get product recordset --

set rs1 = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs1.open "select * from product where P_code like 'ap'", conn1

x = "<table border = 1 width= 1000><tr><th>code<Th>product name<th>Type<th>Price</Tr>"
response.write x

' -- create the table entries for each student --

rs1.movefirst
while not rs1.eof
    x = "<tr><td>" & rs1("P_code") & "<td>" & rs1("P_name") & "<td>" & rs1("P_description") & "<td>" & rs1("P_price") & "</tr>"
    response.write x
    rs1.movenext
wend
response.write "</table>"

' -- close the datbase --
rs1.close
conn1.close
set rs1 = nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call [`MoveFirst()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the recordset is empty, it throws an error.
You should check for [`EOF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
If Not rs1.EOF Then
    rs1.movefirst
    ' your loop
    ' ...
End If
```

Comment: How do you check if a RecordSet is empty? It's entirely possible for a non-empty recordset to have `EOF = true`.